# virtual memory inefficient for paging?

Tags: linux, memory-management, virtual-memory

let's say I write a program which is 100MB and we know that a virtual page in liunx is 4KB by default. so to run the program, there will be 100*1024/4 = 25600 cache misses, isn't that terribly inefficient given the large miss penalties?

Comment: Cache misses occur on a per-cache-line basis, not per-page. The number of cache misses may be less (if some parts of the program are not used, such as code and data to handle errors that do not occur or features that are not used in a particular run) or more (when some parts are evicted from cache by use of other parts and must later be reloaded). However, it is impossible to avoid loading each used line at least once. Various strategies mitigate the costs. For example, the hardware may observe consecutive accesses and attempt to load future lines early, while the program is doing other work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so why not just map the whole program into physical memory in once in the beginning to avoid cache miss penalties

Comment: You are mixing up mappings and storage. Regardless of how the mappings occur the data needs to be stored somewhere that the CPU can use directly. So if your program really needs 100MB of distinct data then there is no getting around the fact that every byte of that data needs to be in cache (or some level of the memory hierarchy)  at some point.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the comment. that's one thing that confuses me about the the loader as it only maps the whole program but not loading them into memory, so the actual loading pages into physical memory it is deferred until an instruction access the address. so why not we just let loader loads every virual pages of the program into physical memory  in the beginning to avoid cache miss penalties?

Comment: The answer to that is very simple. If we could fit everything into cache or memory all the time then we wouldn't need a paging system. So by definition we can't in general pre-load everything into cache or memory.

Comment: @kaylum cache has limit capacity for sure, but at least RAM is quite large in this day and age, for a 8GB memory, why not just load everything into RAM to speed up?

Comment: If you live in a big house by yourself you can do whatever you want. But if you need to share the house with alot of people even a mansion can become crowded. Certainly there are ways to preload and pin data to memory. And that can be used in specialised use cases that require high performance in a narrowly defined environment. But it doesn't work for a general OS which needs to cater to more diverse application workloads.